# So i want to make my bot do a callback like return if the mentioned user already has a role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need help making my bot do something if the user mentioned already has the role specified
Im getting an error that it can define get and it wont execute my if statement
my code is here

```
module.exports = {
name: 'jail',
description: "This command mutes a member a member!",
execute(message, args, Discord) {
    let target = message.mentions.users.first();
    let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
    let test = GuildMember.roles.get(role => role.name === 'Jailed')





    if (message.author.id === memberTarget.id) {
        message.reply('You cant jail yourself dummy'); return;
    } else {

    }


    if (memberTarget === test) {
        message.channel.send('e'); return;
    } else {
      message.channel.send('jailed user')
    }
    
 }
```

The main problem is here

```
    if (memberTarget === test) {
        message.channel.send('e'); return;
    } else {
      message.channel.send('jailed user')
    }
```

Any help is awesome

Note. Debugger said nothing wrong but there is cause my bot shuts down when i execute the command do to an error as it can define get

My problem is i cant get the role and execute my if statement

Comment: What is your actual problem? You need to explain what is or isn't happening that should be different. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: "***The main problem is here***" ... and what is that problem ?

Comment: my problem has been clarified as i cannot get the role i need to execute in an if statement im new to discord.js so please excuse me

Comment: Still unclear what is happening. Are you getting errors or is stuff just not happening? Voting to close until you edit with more clarity. (Advice: use a debugger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
module.exports = {
name: 'jail',
description: "This command mutes a member a member!",
execute(message, args, Discord) {
    let target = message.mentions.users.first();
    let test = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Jailed');


    if (message.author.id === target.id) {
      return message.reply('You cant jail yourself dummy');
    } 

    if (message.guild.member(target).roles.cache.some(role => role.name === test.name)) {
      return message.channel.send('e');
    } else {
      message.guild.member(target).roles.add(test);
      message.channel.send('jailed user')
    }
    
 }
```

I've made some changes in your code. I removed `memberTarget`, because `target` is sufficient in this case. `test` finds the `Jailed` role on the current guild. In the if-statement where we ask if `target` already has the role, I've used a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) Object for `target`. `.some()` returns `true` or `false`. So it searches inside the GuildMember Object of `target` for the `Jailed` role (`test.name`). If it was found on the Object it returns `true` and goes inside the statement. Otherwise it goes to `else`, where the GuildMember `target` gets added to the role `Jailed` (`test`).